# How to capture Contacts and Leads with AMPscript CreateSalesforceObject in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to capture Leads and Contacts using the CreateSalesforceObject.

However, with my code so far, I am only able to capture Leads.

What I want to achieve is that whenever someone submits a form with email @myorganization.com is considered in SF as LEAD (an internal contact for me). This lead must not be duplicated or updated.

And, whenever someone submits a form with email @whateverdomain.com is considered in SF as CONTACT (external contact for me). It needs to be checked if the contact is already in our database and if not just create it.

With my code so far I am able to capture only contacts as LEADS. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

This is my code so far:

```
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN

  /* check if lead already exists */
  SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Lead",
   "Id,Email",
   "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
   )
  
  /* get lead id if lead exists */
  IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN 
  SET @leadId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")
  
  /* update existing lead */
  SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Lead", @leadId,
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "Company", RequestParameter("company")
     )
           
  ELSE
   /* create a new lead */
  SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
        "Lead", 4,
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
        "Email", RequestParameter("email")
       )       
   
  ENDIF       

/* add lead to a campaign*/  
SET @CampaignMember = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
     "CampaignId", "7012p000001vzBFAAY",
     "LeadId", @leadId,
     "Status", "Sent"
      )  

 
]%% 
<h2>Thank you for submitting the form.</h2>

%%[ ELSE ]%%

<table style="padding: 20px;"><tr><td>
      <h2>Please fill in the form:</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
      <label>First name: </label><input type="text" name="firstname" required=""><br>
      <label>Last name: </label><input type="text" name="lastname" required=""><br>
      <label>Company: </label><input type="text" name="company" required=""><br>
      <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" required=""><br>
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>  
</td></tr></table>

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: If you want to create a contact, you need to either lookup or create an account for that contact. You can't just create "orphan" contacts, with no account (unless you are working with Person Accounts)

Comment: You can absolutely create orphan contacts with createSalesforceObject for "normal" contacts. They become invisible for reporting etc, but technically, this works completely fine and you get the ContactId (003xxx) right back. Whereas in case of PersonAccounts, you actually have to CreateSalesforceObject() an Account - Person Accounts are treated like _accounts_  with a recordType by the SFMC connector. After account creation (which returns accountID 001yyy), wait a couple milliseconds and retrieve PersonContactId field (003zzz) off the account.

Comment: Hi @JonasLamberty is it possible for you to assist me with the AMPscript? That would be very much appreciated as I feel stuck with this step and I cannot move forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JonasLamberty correct, that you technically can create orphan contacts, but my point was more that it goes against best practice on SFDC. This will potentially create a number of issues down the line - especially in B2B setups...

Comment: agreed! - Just saying, both from a separation of concerns point of view as from a technical perspective, "determining the right account" based on unformatted free text webform input (such as "company name"), you'll have a hard time as well. Especially if attempted in near-real time. Unless we get a fuzzy retrieve function that doesnt take 3 seconds for one round trip :) So just wanted to clarify that technically, you do not have to find the "correct" contact if your first problem to solve is to receive a 003 ID back for a form submission. As you say, it shouldnt end there.